# Capital words between words - Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find capital words occurring between words using Regex. I want to ignore capital words after.?! and starting of paragraph.

Currently using the code below to find capital letters

[A-Z][^\s]*

```
Example 

A sentence containing Capital letters. How to Extract only capital letters?
```

The Regex should find only Capital and Extract ignoring How and A

Comment: You could use negative lookbehind: [example](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C!%5B.%3F!%5D)%5Cs%2B(%5BA-Z%5D%5Cw*)&test_string=A%20sentence%20containing%20Capital%20letters.%20How%20to%20Extract%20only%20capital%20letters%3F&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution, find all patterns, but use capturing group only on pattern you want to match ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TWw34S/2)):

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"^\s*[A-Z]+|[.?!]\s*[A-Z]+|([A-Z][^\s.?!]*)")


text = "A sentence containing Capital letters. How to Extract only capital letters?"

for m in pat.findall(text):
    if m:
        print(m)
```

Prints:

```
Capital
Extract
```

Comment: This strikes me as unnecessarily complex considering that you can write it, as @Nick does, so that if there is a match the capture group will hold the capitalized word.

Answer (score 3):

@Andrej's solution will return a list with empty values where other capitalised words were found (i.e. `A` and `How`) for your sample data:

```py
['', 'Capital', '', 'Extract']
```

If you want to *only* return the words which are capitalised, then use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![.?!\s])\s+([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

This matches any capitalised word not preceded by a `.`, `,` or `?`. Note we also include `\s` in the negative lookbehind to ensure we don't match a word at the start of a sentence where two spaces have been used e.g.

```
end.  Start
```

would match  `Start` if `\s` was not included in the lookbehind.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/86KXI7/1)

In python:

```
text = 'A sentence containing Capital letters.  How to Extract only capital Letters?'
re.findall('(?<![.?!\s])\s+([A-Z][a-z]*)', text)
```

Output:

```
['Capital', 'Extract', 'Letters']
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit broader match to find capital words occurring between words (not considering specifically `.` `!` and `?`) using a word boundary:

```
\b\s+([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrCZIo/1).

Example

```
import re

s = "A sentence containing Capital letters. How to Extract only capital letters?"
pattern = r"\b\s+([A-Z][a-z]*)"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Capital', 'Extract']
```

Comment: nit-picking I know :) but this won't match `New` in `Chris' New car`

Comment: @Nick Yes I know, that is why I wrote `(not considering specifically . ! and ?)`

Comment: I guess it depends on OPs application as to whether its an issue. Anyway, this is definitely the simplest solution if that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(?:(?:[.!?]\h*[A-Z]|^[A-Z])(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\b[A-Z]\w*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SmcmBW/latest

`(?:(?:<unwanted_option1>|<unwanted_option2>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))` construct disregards all unwanted options, making use of this "trick" (https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). You can easly add more restrictions later. In this case it prevents `.!?` to be before the capital word, as well as the word being the first one in a line.

`\b[A-Z]\w*` picks up all capital words.

Python snippet using the more powerfull `regex` package:

```
import regex

pat = regex.compile(r"(?:(?:[.!?]\h*[A-Z]|^\h*[A-Z])(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\b[A-Z]\w*")


text = "A sentence containing Capital letters. How to Extract only capital letters?"

for m in pat.findall(text):
    if m:
        print(m)
```